# Live event video youtube not work on jwplayer

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api, video-streaming

I have live event on youtube and I tried to embedding on my website using jwplayer. But is not working, when I click play I get a message "Please stand by". I tried resolve problem and I detect a message when I use Inspect element -> console

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (OK) live_state:1 POST
>   https://content.googleapis.com/youtubei/v1/player/live_state?key=AIzaSyCqWzGG81J3LV5dOTXAXoxF87gmDY9PsTc
>   400 (OK)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Jwplayer-6.12</title>
    <script src="jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key = "8CYv4DplMn3p81LXAaR31qpI90gGw4u8TIoK/w==";</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('myElement').setup({
            flashplayer: 'jwplayer.flash.swf',
            file: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyWHDIECRYQ',
            controlbar: 'bottom',
            width: '470',
            height: '320',
            primary: "flash"
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Jwplayer version: 6.12.

Any idea help me resole it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Official Google Documentation for [YouTube APIs Subject to the Deprecation Policy](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube-api-list#deprecation_apis).

**The YouTube ActionScript 3.0 Player API, also known as the YouTube Flash Player API (AS3), has been deprecated as of January 27, 2015. YouTube Flash  embeds have also been deprecated. Please migrate your applications to the IFrame API, which can intelligently use whichever embedded player – HTML () or Flash () – the client supports.**

Please refer to the [YouTube Live Stream API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/) code Samples.

Comment: You can talk in more detail it? I don't understand. Thank you.